# Facebook share button only showing www.example.com

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I added the Facebook "Like" and "Share" button on my site. When I click "Share" I get the usual popup prompting for a message. However, in the pre-filled content area below, it only says

```
www.example.com

www.myurl.com
```

I've added the following and it hasn't helped:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Hello" />
<meta property="og:site_title" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Sample text"/>
<meta property="og:utl" content="www.mysite.com"/>
```

I've tried it with and without the JS SDK. I've also tried the iFrame option.

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=21&amp;appId=1111111111" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is "example.com" in the description field?

Comment: What does Facebook's debug tool ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ ) pick up for the URL you're sharing?

Comment: It shows the same thing. It also says that `og:title www.example.com` and that's not correct. When I view the source of my site it's `<meta property="og:title" content="Hello" />`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Facebook takes a while to index changes. I had to wait about an hour, but now it works. These three meta tags seem to control the content:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Hello" />
<meta property="og:site_title" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Sample text"/>
```